# jsonp call to mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

Is it possible to get cross domain ajax in mvc architectre? I am using jsonp and it works perfectly if both the sites are in localhost. My doubt is that, whether the mvc architecture blocks the jsonp call.??
`<script src="www.example.com"></script>`

`$.ajax({
 url: "www.example.com?id=abc&callback=?",
 dataType: "jsonp"
});`

```
function mycallback(data)
{`alert(data);`

}
```

Comment: Please post your AJAX code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning JSONP data does not come out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 3 and you need write wrapper for it.

What is  JSONP ?

> Server return JSONP with added "?callback=" to the querystring, so
>   server would process the request, and instead of returning a JSON
>   object or XML, it responds with an “application/x-javascript” response
>   using the callback parameter as a wrapper function, so when request is
>   answered, the browser will execute the JavaScript returned.

Comment: Hi Reno, thank you for your reply. I wrote the wrapper function for it. Its working good(as localhost).. My question is that, if I host my mvc application in a global url, will this code work?

Comment: MVC framework doesn't block it. Server should not block also, becouse it works same as accessing simple javascript file from your server. It can be problem if your page using https and your request for javascript is over http protocal.